# Jasper report -Not able to get repeated elements inside same tag but in different parent nodes

Tags: xpath, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am very new to the jasper reporting and was trying some simple tutorials, I have following XML input file as datasource, problem I getting is it gives me first file name from both nodes twice and not the unique one(like source1.c and header1.h 2 times).

```
<SourceCodeFiles>
    <FileName name="source1.c"/>
    <FileName name="source2.c"/>
</SourceCodeFiles>    
<HeaderFiles>
  <FileName name="header1.h"/>
  <FileName name="header2.h"/>
</HeaderFiles>
```

[image: This is the query dialog screenshot, I think XPath expressions are looking fine, I also set "FileName" tag as record name for both of its parent nodes.]

Answer (score 0):

u can use union operator
example:

> `/SourceCodeFiles/FileName[1] | /HeaderFiles/FileName[1]`